# Encrypted luks SSD from dead laptop in another laptop / data recovery

Tags: linux, ssd, luks, recovery

Recently my laptop died, there is no chance to save the laptop anymore. On the laptop i was running Elementary OS. While installing i choose the encryption with LUkS option.

Now i have another laptop, i want to recover the files / run the whole OS, with all data like the original dead laptop.

How i proceed? Can i simply put the SSD in my new laptop? The SSD is a INTEL SSD 545S Seroes 128GB 2.5" 6Gb/s sata SSD. It came from a Librem 13 v4 laptop and at the moment i have a MSI GV62 8RE laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be able to recover your data and you may be able to just swap the disk into a new computer – as long as the disk itself is not broken or was somehow compromised by the dying laptop. I've done such encrypted disk transplantations before.

If this is your only disk, chances are you can move it into the new laptop and  boot from it. But your mileage may vary, because the OS is suddenly confronted with a new hardware configuration that it may not play nicely with (networking, display adapter, etc.). So I'd rather do a fresh installation on a new disk and then copy the data from the old disk:

After OS setup just connect the old encrypted disk via a USB adapter. Once the disk is connected find its device file (`lsblck`) and open it. E.g.:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 olddisk
```

You should now be able to mount it like so:

```
mount /dev/mapper/olddisk /mnt/
```

Copy your data and unmount/close it when you're done:

```
umount /mnt
cryptsetup luksClose olddisk
```